# Fetching all users data to app from parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, coronasdk, fetch

I am a rookie in network communications (parse.com)
I can send data from my app to user or class at parse.com. After different users send the data to parse.com, I need to fetch data to other mobile phones from parse.com. I use corona sdk.
Would anyone know the codes to simply download all available data from different users to the app.
Many thanks

Comment: network.request( baseUrl .. objectClass, "GET", networkListener,  params)

Comment: adding this .."/".. id after objectClass will require to include an objedtId while above downloads everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

network.request( baseUrl .. objectClass, "GET", networkListener, params)

adding this .."/".. id after objectClass will require to include an objedtId while above downloads everything